# Prove that if p is an odd prime then $x^2=2 \pmod p$ has solutions if and only if $p\equiv \pm 1 \pmod 8$

Tags: number-theory

I was going to break up $p$ into $8k+1$ and $8k+7$. Using this, I can plug that in for p and then solve using this.

Comment: Hint: You can use Euler's criterion. Page 18 of: http://www.math.brown.edu/~jhs/MA0042/FRINTNewCh2324.pdf provides more details. I've got to go to class.

Comment: This thread on MO might help: <http://mathoverflow.net/questions/83060/prime-factors-of-x2-2>.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof that $\left( \frac{2}{p} \right) = (-1)^{(p^2-1)/8}$, which is basically what you are looking for:

[Legendre symbol, second supplementary law](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180002/legendre-symbol-second-supplementary-law/180022#180022)

This says that $2$ is a [quadratic residue](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticResidue.html) $\bmod{p}$ if and only if $(p^2-1)/8$ is even. (Saying that $2$ is a quadratic residue is the same as saying that there is a solution to $x^2 \equiv 2 \pmod{p}$.) It is not difficult to check that: 
$(p^2-1)/8 = (p-1)(p+1)/8$
is even iff one of the factors $p-1,p+1$ is divisible by $8$.