# Integers $x,y$ so that $2y^2+3\mid x^2-2$

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

The question is

> Do there exist integers $x,y$ so that $2y^2+3$ divides $x^2-2$?

Apparently, this problem can be solved with quadratic reciprocity. Is there any simpler way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $2 y^2 + 3 \equiv 3 \mod 8$ if $y$ is even, $\equiv 5 \mod 8$ if $y$ is odd.  Therefore $2 y^2 + 3$ must have some prime factor $\equiv 3$ or $5 \mod 8$.
But $2$ is not a quadratic residue for such a prime: see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180002/legendre-symbol-second-supplementary-law/180022#180022).